model the inverse of hasManyThrough relationship using a pivot model
I have the following models/tables:
branch:
    id - integer

department:
    id - integer

teacher:
    id  - integer
    branch_department_id - integer

branch_department:
    id - integer
    branch_id - integer
    department_id - integer


each branch has many departments through the pivot table branch_department
each branch_department has many teachers
In a previous question i asked to make a HasManyThrough relationship between the branch and the teacher
Whic was solved to using this:
public function teachers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Teacher::class,
        BranchDepartment::class,
        secondKey: 'branch_department_id',
    );
}

Now i want to model the inverse of this relationship.
so that from the teacher model i get the branch that it belongs to
How can I define this?

Simply you can use belongsTo like this in laravel. You can try this.
public function branch()
{
    return $this->belongsToThrough(
        Branch::class,
        BranchDepartment::class,
        'branch_department_id', // Foreign key on Teacher table
        'id',                   // Local key on Branch table
        'id',                   // Local key on BranchDepartment table
        'branch_id'             // Foreign key on BranchDepartment table
    );
}


There is no belongsToThrough in laravel

^ Correct, however this is a 3rd-party package that makes this method available: https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through
